Do idempotents in an abelian category constitute a lattice?
Consider an object $X$ in an abelian category $\mathcal{C}$. We define $\text{Idem}_{\mathcal{C}}(X)$ as the set of idempotent endomorphisms $a$ in $\text{End}_{\mathcal{C}}(X)$, meaning that $a \circ a = a$. This set naturally forms a partially ordered set (poset) where $a \leq b$ if and only if $a \circ b = a = b \circ a$.
The question we are investigating is whether $\text{Idem}_{\mathcal{C}}(X)$ possesses the structure of a lattice. Specifically, does every pair of elements in $\text{Idem}_{\mathcal{C}}(X)$ have a unique supremum (least upper bound) and a unique infimum (greatest lower bound) with respect to this poset structure?
Recall that an abelian category $\mathcal{C}$ is idempotent-complete, which means that for each element $a$ in $\text{Idem}_{\mathcal{C}}(X)$, there exists an object $Y$ in $\mathcal{C}$ along with morphisms $i_Y: Y \to X$ and $p_Y: X \to Y$ satisfying $p_Y \circ i_Y = \text{id}_Y$ and $i_Y \circ p_Y = a$. Here, $i_Y$ serves as a split monomorphism with $p_Y$ as its left inverse. Furthermore, the triple $(Y, i_Y, p_Y)$ is unique up to isomorphism (refer to this discussion).
Conversely, for any such triple $(Y, i_Y, p_Y)$, the composite $i_Y \circ p_Y$ yields an element in $\text{Idem}_{\mathcal{C}}(X)$. As a result, $\text{Idem}_{\mathcal{C}}(X)$ can be interpreted as the set of equivalence classes of these triples. The poset structure then corresponds to $(Y, i_Y, p_Y) \leq (Z, i_Z, p_Z)$ if and only if $p_Z \circ i_Y: Y \to Z$ is a split monomorphism with a left inverse given by $i_Z \circ p_Y$. Thus $(p_Z \circ i_Y) \circ (i_Z \circ p_Y) \in \text{Idem}_{\mathcal{C}}(Z)$.
Thus, the core of our inquiry is whether these equivalence classes form a lattice under this order. Insights or references on whether this poset structure always yields a lattice would be greatly appreciated.
We might anticipate that $(Y, i_Y, p_Y) \wedge (Z, i_Z, p_Z)$ would be determined by the pullback of $(Y, i_Y)$ and $(Z, i_Z)$. However, this discussion highlights that the pullback of two split monomorphisms might not necessarily result in split monomorphisms.

cross-post: https://mathoverflow.net/q/481460/34538

I wonder: would it also be correct to say that it's equivalent to the poset of direct sum decompositions $X = A \oplus B$, with $(A, B) \le (A', B')$ if and only if $A \subseteq A'$ and $B' \subseteq B$?

Or maybe you need $(A, B) \le (A', B')$ if and only if $A$ decomposes further as $A' \oplus A''$ and $B' = B \oplus A''$.

Interestingly, in the example from the link where the intersection isn't a direct summand i.e. in the category of $\mathbb{C}[t]$-modules, $M := (\mathbb{C}[t] / \langle t^2 \rangle)^2$, $a := ((m, n) \mapsto (m, 0))$, $b := ((m, n) \mapsto (m, tm))$, they do seem to have a meet $a \wedge b = 0$.  Outline of proof: if $c\le a, b$, then because $ac = bc = c$, the image of $c$ is contained in the equalizer of $a,b$ which is $\langle (t, 0) \rangle$.  From that, it's easy to see that $c^2 = 0$, so $c = 0$.

@DanielSchepler Yes, however, I anticipate that the following counter-example will also have a $\mathbb{C}$-linear analogue: https://mathoverflow.net/a/481467/34538.

While I know to little about categories, it seems to me that that operation on the endomorphisms is clearly associative, right? That is the case for usual composition of maps or morphisms. If so, then given that you're also considering it to be commutative, then the set of idempotents form a semilattice (idempotent commutative semigroup). So, from your definition of the underlying order, you already have the infimum of two elements: $a \wedge b = a \circ b$.

If you also have a common upper bound for each pair of elements, then their join would be the meet of the common upper bounds. But of course in the infinite case this could not work. And then again, I might have missed something and the meet operation is also not defined as in the above comment.

@amrsa Unfortunately, the composition of endomorphisms can be noncommutative.

@SebastienPalcoux Ok, then I misunderstood. Of course endomorphisms don't have to commute, but from the context, I thought that would be the definition (or a consequence) of abelian category. Glad you found the solution elsewhere.

Remy van Dobben de Bruyn provided this answer on MathOverflow.
Following the approach of Jeremy Rickard, it can be adapted to create a $\mathbb{C}$-linear example. This involves considering the category of $\mathbb{C}[t]$-modules, where we take $ X = (\mathbb{C}[t]/(t^2))^3 $ and define the submodules $ A = \langle (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0) \rangle $ and $ B = \langle (1, 0, t), (0, 1, 0) \rangle $.
